# Connecting Spring Boot app to the MySQL Database

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, database-connection, connection-string

I have created a Spring Boot app and I am trying to connect the same to MySQL database.  The database.sql file that I have included looks like below:

[Database.sql snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQ3h7.png)

However, for some reasons, I am unable to select any `Name` and `Database` options from the down drop.  However, I am able to run the commands from the local terminal.

Also, the `.jar` file that is created fails to run with the following error:

[.jar file error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdwXx.png)

My application.properties file looks like below:

```
#spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/restapi
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=<my password here>
```

Could someone please point out how I could establish the connectivity?  Thanks!

My `pom.xml` is as follows:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>me.boy</groupId>
  <artifactId>SpringBootRESTAPI</artifactId>
  <version>3.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <!-- <name>SpringBootRESTAPI</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url> -->

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- JUnit -->    
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Boot Dependency -->
    <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JPA Dependency -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- MySQL Connector -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Can you share your pom.xml?

Comment: Exclude auto configuration of DataSource in the Spring Boot application class. We can do this using EnableAutoConfiguration annotation like:
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})

Comment: @Adya, absolutely.  I have edited my question to include my `pom.xml` file. Thanks for all your help! :)

Comment: Also, @Adya, I am not using any auto configuration of Data Source in the Spring Boot Application class.